# Bootstrap isn't doing what it should do

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So my problem is that Bootstrap is not working for my HTML Code. Here is a little bit of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center" style="">
    <h1 style="font-size: 112px;">Test</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 650px;"class="dropdown">
<a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Test</button></a>
  <div style="position relative; left: -30px;"class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When you resize the Page the only thing that resizes too is only the Big Test. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you *expect* Bootstrap to be doing?

Comment: That is malformed HTML - it is missing a `</nav>` at least. Some of the `style` attributes are also invalid. Like `style="position relative;` is missing a `:`.

Comment: "Am i doing something wrong?" — It looks like you have added Bootstrap expecting it to be a magical salve that will make you a responsive design. It isn't. If you want a responsive design then you have to design one. Bootstrap has some prewritten CSS that can help, but you need to follow its rules (it has quite a lot of documentation that you need to read) at the expense of having class soup. I prefer to just write CSS with semantic HTML and meaningful class names.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of missing/wrong tags are added like `<nav>` and `<div>.`

1. If you want to apply the style to your element, then you can do it using [external](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) stylesheet. Inline stylesheet is not recommended.
2. include the Bootstrap JavaScript and other JS files in the end of body tag, not in the head.
3. Go through the [documents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) for more.

I have formatted the code and also included an external stylesheet which might help you.

```css
      body{
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div  class="allign-center">
        <h1 class="h1">Test</h1>
        </div>
    
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```